# how to loop for this code, every time loop happens it should take next row data from excel

Tags: automated-testing

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import utils.ReadExcelFile;

public class TestUser {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, InterruptedException
{
    String driverPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/DriverFiles/chromedriver.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath); 
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();         
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    ReadExcelFile xllib= new ReadExcelFile();
    String url = xllib.getExcelData("Login",1,0);
    driver.get(url); //Enter the url in the browser;
    String userName = xllib.getExcelData("Login",1,1);
    driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys(userName); //Enter user name;
    String password = xllib.getExcelData("Login",1,2);
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password); //Enter password;
    driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();  //Click on login button;
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main_nav']/ul/li[9]/a/span[2]")).click(); //Click on Administration tab;
    // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ALL_CONTENT_ID']/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a")).click(); //Click on User tab in Administration ;
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='page_content']/div[1]/div[2]/a[2]/i")).click(); //Click on Add User;
    String firstName = xllib.getExcelData("AddUser",1,3);
    driver.findElement(By.id("firstName")).sendKeys(firstName);
    String lastName = xllib.getExcelData("AddUser",1,4);
    driver.findElement(By.id("lastName")).sendKeys(lastName);
    String userId = xllib.getExcelData("AddUser",1,5);
    driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys(userId);
    String emailId = xllib.getExcelData("AddUser",1,6);
    driver.findElement(By.id("emailId")).sendKeys(emailId); 
    String phoneNo = xllib.getExcelData("AddUser",1,7);
    driver.findElement(By.id("phoneNo")).sendKeys(phoneNo); 
    Thread.sleep(2000); 
    String password1 = xllib.getExcelData("AddUser",1,8);
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password1);  
    String confirmPassword = xllib.getExcelData("AddUser",1,9);
    driver.findElement(By.id("confirmPassword")).sendKeys(confirmPassword); 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='entityId_ms']")).click(); //Click on Entity drop down;
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ALL_CONTENT_ID']/div[5]/ul/li[2]/label/span")).click(); //Select pridction check box;
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='entityId_ms']")).click(); //close the  Entity drop down
    String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/UploadFiles/Admin_M.jpg"; //Select upload image icon;
    driver.findElement(By.id("file")).sendKeys(filePath); //Select uploading file;
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='userDetailsForm']/div[4]/div/div/div/label")).click(); //click on All View Access;
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='userDetailsForm']/div[5]/div/div/div/div/label[1]")).click(); //Select role as admin;
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='userDetailsForm']/div[6]/input")).click();   //Click on create button; 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ALL_CONTENT_ID']/div[5]/div[3]/div/button")).click(); //Click on Ok button in the popup message;
    driver.quit();
            }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `for`loop for iterating the code multiple times.

```java
    for(i=0;i<rownum;i++){
      driver.get(url); //Enter the url in the browser;
      String userName = xllib.getExcelData("Login",i,1);
      driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys(userName); //Enter user name;
      String password = xllib.getExcelData("Login",i,2);
      //your remaining code.....
    }
```

The code will iterate for the number of rows in the excel sheet. Check if this helps.

Comment: How do you get rownum?

Comment: @AlexeyR.  how about  
int rownum = xllib.getLastRowNum(); ??

Comment: I do not know. If I knew I wouldn't ask.

Comment: @KetanDeshpande It will be better to use XSSF or HSSF libraries for reading/writing from/to excel files...